# Computation hangs: rstan, plyr, and doMC

Tags: r, dplyr, domc, rstan

I am trying to run a simple `rstan` example using `plyr` and `doMC` for parallel computation. The following code completes normally if I comment out `registerDoMC(cores = 2)` near the bottom, but as is, my `R` session hangs indefinitely on the call to `adply`. I am using R version 3.3.0 with the R GUI on Mac OS 10.11.5.

**EDIT**: Oddly enough, this works on a Linux server and my Mac via `R CMD BATCH` on the command line. Still no R GUI, though.

```
library(rstan)
library(doMC)
library(plyr)

model = stan_model(model_code = "
data {
  int k; // number of observations per subject
  real theta; // hierarchical mean of the mu's, estimated beforehand (empirical Bayes)
  vector[k] subject; // subject-specific data
}
parameters {
  real mu; // subject-specific mean
}
model { 
  mu ~ normal(theta, 1) ;
  for(i in 1:k)
    subject[i] ~ normal(mu, 1);
}")

single_subject = function(model, subject, theta){
  diverge = TRUE
  attempt = 1

  while (diverge) {
    print(paste("Attempt", attempt))
    .mcmc = sampling(model, pars = "mu", iter = 2000*attempt, thin = attempt, verbose = F,
                     data = list(k = length(subject), theta = theta, subject = subject))
    .summary = summary(.mcmc)$summary
    diverge = any(.summary[,"n_eff"] < 1000)
    attempt = attempt + 1
  }

  .summary["mu",]
}

n = 100 # number of subjects
k = 32 # number of observations per subject
dataset = matrix(rnorm(n*k), ncol = k)
theta = 0 # could be estimated from the data beforehand

start = proc.time()
out = adply(dataset, 1, function(subject) single_subject(model, subject, theta))
serial_time = proc.time() - start

start = proc.time()
registerDoMC(cores = 2)
out = adply(dataset, 1, 
  function(subject) single_subject(model, subject, theta),
  .parallel = T,
  .paropts = list(.export=c("single_subject", "model", "subject", "theta"), 
                  .packages="rstan"))
registerDoSEQ()
parallel_time = proc.time() - start

cat("Serial time:\n")
print(serial_time)

cat("Parallel time:\n")
print(parallel_time)

write.csv(out, "mu.csv")
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not simply passing `cores = 2` to `sampling`? In the past, forking the process via DoMC, mclapply(), etc. wasn't recommended in a GUI, although RStudio got it to work. If you do parallelize the chains with some external mechanism, then you need to be sure to pass them a common `seed` but a unique `chain_id` in order to reduce the chance of overlap in the periods of the pseudo-random number generators

Comment: For this example, I prefer parallelizing over the rows of a dataset rather than running simultaneous chains. I only use 4 chains, but the number of rows is much larger, so I expect a greater efficiency gain as the number of cores increases.

Comment: I checked just now, and Rstudio works for this example too.